# Dump SQL tables to CSV using OpenCSV

Tags: java, mysql, opencsv

I am trying to write the data from ResultSet to csv file using Netbeans and OpenCSV. I added OpenCSV library:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*;

...

 try {   CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\test2.csv"), ',');
                        writer.writeAll(rs,includeHeaders);

                     }

                     catch (Exception e){}
                }
```

However I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable includeHeaders
  location: class DBConnect
```

Am I missing some other imports?

Comment: Have you declared includeHeaders variable?

Comment: I haven't as I assumed this was imported variable as it is on the basic openCSV tutorial. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CSVWriter.writeAll(rs,includeHeaders)`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeAll%28java.sql.ResultSet,%20boolean%29) expects a **ResultSet** and a **boolean** as an argument. you need to declare includeHeaders.

or simply pass the boolean values like

```
     writer.writeAll(rs,true);
     writer.writeAll(rs,false);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's working but the file I get is empty?  Database works fine.

Comment: I will but need to wait 3 min. Any suggestions for empty csv file? I check and rs contains valid data.